# Printing using the double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, printing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int mytype[2][3];
mytype **ipp;

int main()
{
int tab[2][3];
mytype *pointer;
pointer = &tab;
ipp = &pointer;
(*pointer)[0][3] = 2;
int myint = (*pointer)[0][3];
printf("%d\n",myint);
receiver();
return 0;
}

void receiver()
{
int myint1 = (**ipp);
printf("%d\n",myint1);
}
```

I am trying to point a pointer to a 2D array and print the value at a given position. I am able to do this but I don't know how to print the same value when I point a pointer to this pointer. Can someone help me out? I am new to the double pointers. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a double pointer (`mytype **`). So you will need to dereference it twice to get to the 2d array. In `receiver()`

```
int myint1 = (**ipp)[0][3];
printf("%d\n",myint1);
```

This would correctly print the value. Earlier you were assigning to an `int` variable`int(*)[3]`. Compiler threw the error of [error: invalid conversion from `'int (*)[3]'` to `'int'`] (To give you the idea of from where this `int(*)[3]` comes - the 2d array decays into pointer to first element - which is a pointer to an array of 3 `int` elements - `int (*)[3]`).